# how to convert dates to week numbers

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, week-number

I need to do my reporting on week on week basis but my week number should start from 1st day of month

here is my sample data:

```
report_date  Vol 
01 nov 2014   23
03 nov 2014   34
16 nov 2014   56
30 nov 2014   44
```

Desired output

```
Week no  Vol
1         57
2         56
3         0
4         44
```

hope its clear

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since your desired output include "zero" rows as well, and assuming you'd like this report to work across multiple months as well:

```
WITH sample_data AS
  (SELECT DATE '2014-11-01' AS report_date, 23 AS vol FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2014-11-03', 34 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2014-11-16', 56 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2014-11-30', 44 FROM DUAL)
 ,weeks AS
  (SELECT report_month
         ,TO_CHAR(ROWNUM) AS week_no
   FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT
                  TRUNC(report_date,'MM') AS report_month
           FROM   sample_data)
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(report_month),'W')))
SELECT TO_CHAR(weeks.report_month,'Month') AS "Month"
      ,weeks.week_no AS "Week no"
      ,NVL(sum(sample_data.vol),0) AS "Vol"
FROM   weeks
LEFT JOIN sample_data
ON     weeks.report_month = TRUNC(report_date,'MM')
AND    weeks.week_no = to_char(report_date,'W')
GROUP BY weeks.report_month, weeks.week_no ORDER BY 1,2;
```

We determine the number of weeks in each month of the source data by using the `LAST_DAY` function, and we do a hierarchical query (`CONNECT BY LEVEL <= n`) to generate one row for each week in each month.

The expected output should be:

```
Month    Week no Vol
======== ======= ===
November 1        57
November 2         0
November 3        56
November 4         0
November 5        44
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(report_date, 'W'), sum(vol)
from your_table
group by to_char(report_date, 'W');
```

> **W** Week of month (1-5) where week 1 starts on the first day of the
>   month and ends on the seventh.

Comment: Almost: he wants 0 for empty weeks